# Debugging slow network performance on a specific machine

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet

I have the following case:

- Desktop and laptop plugged-in to the same switch
- OS: Arch Linux (up-to-date, same configuration, same kernel, ...)
- The speed in LAN when testing between both machines with iperf reaches the network's 1gbps limit. Both machines correctly report 1gbps link in dmesg (laptopt with alx driver, desktop with igb driver).
- The desktop works as expected, speedtest reports me 300 or so mbit/s today.
- Ethernet cables are fine and have been swapped to check.

Now, the laptop:

- I get a lot of timeouts on random websites
- Speedtest to the exact same IP than the desktop does gives me between 15 and 20mbit/s

What can I do to debug this? I don't understand where the problem can come from.

Comment: What I do in Windows as an initial step is update Computer drivers and driver firmware (possibly BIOS), then router firmware, then restart everything and check.

Comment: Do you have access to a USB Ethernet adapter? Try it on both machines to see if it has to do with the difference in NICs/drivers.

Comment: I just tried on windows and there I get full speed on the laptop - but I don't have an USB ethernet adapter to test